# broadcasting in a LAN/between interconnected LAN's using android

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, android-broadcast, wifip2p

I have to design an app in android for voice over WiFi communication for my university. Our university's infrastructure consists of interconnected LAN's(interconnection between multiple routers at different hostels and classrooms) and also a few wireless access point(all having wired interconnection). The speed of the university LAN is around  100Mbps. What I need my app to do is discover via broadcasting other instances of the app running in various devices within the campus(same android app will be installed on all devices),both within the same subnet(router) and also devices connected to other routers within the campus. The ultimate goal is to also enable end users who connect their phones using connectify me to their laptops to be able to communicate with each other,provided both the laptops are connected to the university network(may not share same subnet).However, even if that is not posible, atleast two devices residing on two different subnets must be able to discover each other. Thereafter, voice calls can be made from one device to another. The idea for discovery is via broadcast messages. There would be no central server. I am new to network  programming and also android programming(though I have prior knowledge of core java). Kindly help with the procedure to broadcast messages across my university network for the initial device discovery stage and also suggest any protocols that I need to learn and any codecs for conversion from voice to data. Any other help regarding design and implementation would also be welcomed with gratitude. Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, breaking your text into paragraphs will make your question much easier to read ...

Comment: you can use multicast approach rather than unicast broadcast..something like Kouchat for Android

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast does not cross subnets. For instance pinging `255.255.255.255` on a class C network is the same as pinging `A.B.C.255` with A.B.C being the first 3 Octets of your IP address.

Since you mentioned

> broadcast messages across my university network

I believe you want to reach destinations beyond your own subnet. You could do so by using DHCP , which would use the routers as a relay agent to forward broadcasts to different subnets. However, I would rather use `Multicast` as `eee` mentioned earlier.